# When I imput score values, it returns an incorrect result

Tags: c++

I have just recently started programming in c++, and have attempted to create a program which returns your Grade, based on the score that you input. 
However, whilst the A grade is correct, I have noticed the other grades returning some wrong result. I will Paste the code below, and if anyone could have a look at it I would be extremely grateful!

```
#include <stdafx.h>                
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printgrade(double score);

int main() {

double score;

std::cout << "Hello, Please enter your score: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> score;

printgrade(score);

system("pause");

return 0;


}

void printgrade (double score) {
if (score >= 90.0)
    std::cout << " A " << std::endl;
else if (score <= 80.0)
    std::cout << " B " << std::endl;
else if (score >= 70.0)
    std::cout << " C " << std::endl;
else if (score >= 60.0)
    std::cout << " D " << std::endl;
else if (score >= 50.0)
    std::cout << " E " << std::endl;
else if (score >= 40.0)
    std::cout << " F " << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `else if (score <= 80.0)` <- this line

Comment: There's an error in one of the conditions: `score <= 80.0` should read `score >= 80.0`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Just an observation (not related to the question, which has been answered) - you have "using namespace std" in your program so it isn't necessary to also use std:: inside the program.  For example just "cin >> score" would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (score >= 90.0)
    std::cout << " A " << std::endl;
else if (score <= 80.0)
    std::cout << " B " << std::endl;
else if (score >= 70.0)
    std::cout << " C " << std::endl;
```

It's that `score <= 80` condition that should be changed to `>=`.

As it stands now, you'll get (in order of preference) an `A` for `>= 90`, a `B` for anything `<= 80`, and a `C` for anything `>= 70`. Since that covers *all* possibilities, no other grades are possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't even realize that haha